# SQL server Audit- Does it cause overhead

Tags: sql-server, audit

If I enable Audit on production databases that have over 100 m rows and have constant DML statements going (24 hours), is that going to cause any overhead on SQL server performance or tempdb? Does that increase the .ldf log size of the database its monitoring?

Any issues this can cause that I should be aware of?

Comment: Shouldn't impact the log directly but nothing is free. How expensive will it be? You'll have to test.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/sql/sql-server-2008/dd392015(v=sql.100) should be a good going: They have pretty good test numbers

Comment: If I made you write down everything you were doing while you were doing it, how fast would you be able to do things? Left foot, right foot, chew gum.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> If I enable Audit on production databases that have over 100 m rows and have constant DML statements going (24 hours), is that going to cause any overhead on SQL server performance or tempdb?

To directly answer your question, yes. Auditing always has overhead. If you have to write down what you've done and call extra code that wouldn't normally be called then by definition it'll have overhead.

Whether that overhead is appreciable enough to cause you an issue we can't say. This is completely dependent upon:

- How the auditing is implemented
- What you are auditing
- Where you are holding your audit information

There will be a different in performance using some 3rd party solution utilizing detours/iat/eat hijacking/whatever versus a trace vs security (extended events). Your mileage will vary with all of these (not all supported) choices.

> Does that increase the .ldf log size of the database its monitoring?

If, for some reason, you keep the audit records in a table in that database then yes... otherwise, no.

Comment: Thanks much. I am planning to keep the records on the file server not in one of the databases.  Just thinking of using the SQL audits available in SSMS under security. It will be auditing one table that has over 100 m rows.

Comment: @Sarah Number of rows in the table is largely irrelevant, it is how much activity you are auditing.